# Encrypting images in CSS

Tags: css, image, encryption

How can I protect my background images like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johniehjelm/eECc6/
?

Comment: That's a [base64-dataURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Embedding_an_image_via_data:_url).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background images used in the example are called data URIs. They aren't really protected, the data is converted to base 64, that's all. Just like all the other answers have said. The primary purpose of this technique is to reduce the number of HTTP requests. So instead of 10 requests for 10 different images there will only be one for the CSS.

More information about the hows and whys of this technique can be found here http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

The above site also has links on the limitations of data URIs (IE7 and below don't support them) and it has links to other sites with ways to get around those limitations.

Answer (score 2):

This is not encryption. This is encoding. The image data is base-64 encoded ([described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Embedding_an_image_via_data%3a_url)); modern browsers can decode and display an image encoded this way.

PS: To save the image, all a user has to do is right click and click *save image as...*.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't encrypting the image. You're just encoding it in base-64 and shoving that string directly into the CSS file's `url()`.

I've used this tool whenever I had to do this: http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really encrypted and I don't believe it would protect your image in anyway (if your browser can display it, you can save it).

It is simply base64 encoded and placed inline in the CSS.

There are lots of tools (and sample code) around for converting a binary file in into a base64 encoded string. Here is a tool that I found quickly with with a google search: http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter

Thanks,

Hal

Answer (score 0):

Actually its not protection. You can convert images in base64 format and use them in CSS

First result in Google
http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter/Create